# Open only one popup tab with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wondered how to open only one tab and before you can open another tab, the previous tab has to be closed. I open the tab with a button click,

```
onClick(){
        let url = this.router.createUrlTree(['/user/', this.id]);
        window.open(url.toString(), "_blank", "resizable=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, status=no, directories=no, location=no, width=1000, height=600, left=" + horizontal + " top=100 " );
        console.log(this.data.maxtab);
        }
```

It leads to a component "user" which is nested in another component.

And when one is opened and try to open another component, the one, which is opened should be focused.

I tried to change a variable, which I called maxtab on ngOnDestroy of the component but it does not work. How can I achieve it? With OnBeforeunload with JS (looked it up but could not implement it) or are there another ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

declare a variable in the component.ts

```
private mywindow;
```

Now in your function, try this:

```
if(this.mywindow) {
 this.mywindow.close();
}
this.mywindow = window.open(url.toString(), "_blank", "resizable=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, status=no, directories=no, location=no, width=1000, height=600, left=" + horizontal + " top=100 " );
```

Comment: We define mywindow on the bottom. If I do it like that mywindow in the if condition is not found... but I understand the principke. Could you be more precise? It only should close the pop up window if there exist one not the start window, which is always there, maybe there lies the mistake?

Comment: I edited my answer based on what you have said in the above comment. If this is not what you need, can you explain your requirement a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

You should use name parameter, to provide name of window.

```
window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)
```

example:

```
var myWindow = window.open(url.toString(), "mypopup", "resizable=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, status=no, directories=no, location=no, width=1000, height=600, left=10 top=100");
if (myWindow) {myWindow.focus()}
```

You can give any name in place of "mypopup".

With that you need not to close the earlier popup, it will open the new url, with in same popup window.

myWindow.focus() will set focus to the already open popup, while opening the new url provided.